# Search and delete registry values containing string using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to find all the values recursively that contains this sub-string in it name : "~fr-FR~".

```
$registry = Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\PackageDetect\" -Recurse 

Foreach($a in $registry) {
($a | Get-ItemProperty).Psobject.Properties |
    Where-Object { $_.Name -like '*~fr-FR~*' } 

}
```

At this point I can retrieve all the values filtered recursively. Pasted below is example of one of the results:

```
MemberType      : NoteProperty
IsSettable      : True
IsGettable      : True
Value           : 3
TypeNameOfValue : System.Int32
Name            : Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy-ClientTools-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~fr-FR~10.0.17134.1
IsInstance      : True
```

How do I remove the sub-string?

Comment: Uninstall `fr` language pack?

Comment: If you really want to do it this way, what's wrong with Remove-Item and Remove-ItemProperty commands?